# How to get bengali font script as output written within verbatim package?

Tags: verbatim

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
$\alpha=\beta$
Here is my text.  
এখানে আমার টেক্সট ।

\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

This gives the following output :

```
$\alpha=\beta$
Here is my text.
```

But want the following output :

```
$\alpha=\beta$
Here is my text.  
এখানে আমার টেক্সট ।
```

Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: I have used 'India Bengali ' font.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please consider augmenting your code snippet to form a full MWE (minimum working example). That way, it'll become clear (i) whether you're using pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX, and (ii) how you're loading the font `India Bengali`. Thanks.

Comment: I am using pdfLaTeX. To load  follow the step(in Ubuntu10.04)  System => Preferences =>
Keyboard =>Layouts
=>Add =>By language =>In the
'language:' box select
'Bengali '(or any other language
you like) => In the
'variants:' box select the required
option as you like
=> Add => Close.

Comment: Is there any alternative way to get this output?

Answer (score 2):

From the question, it's not really clear how you are loading a specialist font, if at all. What is certain is that pdfLaTeX is not a good choice for working work Bengali input or similar in verbatim mode. I would strongly recommend either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX plus the `fontspec` package, in the form

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{<name>} % which supports Bengali
\setmonofont{<name>} % which supports Bengali
\usepackage{verbatim}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
$\alpha=\beta$
Here is my text.  
এখানে আমার টেক্সট ।

\end{verbatim}

\end{document}
```

The font name you gave is rather generic, which prevents me checking, but an issue you will face is glyph coverage. I've no idea if there is a font which supports Bengali and provides monospaced output: you may have to modify your `verbatim` to use a proportional font. To help further, we'll need a link to the exact font in use.

Answer (score 1):

I have written a package [`latexbangla`](http://latexbangla.com) to specifically address Bangla related typesetting issues. It fully supports Bangla text in `verbatim` environment and modifies the `banglattfont` to make it mono-spaced.

**Sample code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[banglamainfont=Kalpurush, 
            banglattfont=Siyam Rupali
           ]{latexbangla}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\begin{verbatim}
\textbf{ফার্মার লিটল থিওরেম(Fermat's Little Theorem):} $p$ একটি মৌলিক সংখ্যা 
এবং $n$ একটি পূর্ণসংখ্যা হলে, 
\[n^p\equiv n\pmod{n}\]
এখানে, বাংলা টেলিটাইপ(Teletype)টেক্সট প্রদর্শনে সিয়াম রূপালি ফন্ট ব্যবহৃত হয়েছে।
\end{verbatim}
কিন্তু মূল ডকুমেন্টে বাংলা টেক্সট প্রদর্শনে কালপুরুষ ফন্ট ব্যবহৃত হয়েছে।
\end{document}
```

[image]